# Some questions about independence

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have some questions about independence which I don't know where to look at.

I will denote by

- r.v. the random variable
- $\perp$ symbol the independence relation.

1. Given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ r.v., is it true that they are independent $\iff \mathbb{P}(X_i, X_j) = \mathbb{P}(X_i) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_j)$?

I think the answer to this one is no because I should check every finite subset joint probability.

2. Given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y$ r.v., is it true that if $Y \perp X_i \; \forall i =1,\ldots,n$ then $Y \perp X_1,\ldots,X_n$?

For the same reasons of the previous one I think the answer is no.

The last bit: I know that given $(X_1,\ldots,X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots,X_m)$ Gaussian random vector is true that if $Cov(X_i,X_j) = 0 \; \forall i=1,\ldots,n$ and $j=n+1,\ldots,m$ then $(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \perp (X_{n+1},\ldots,X_m)$.

There exists an analogous result for a set of arbitrary r.v. (not necessarily gaussian) $(X_i)_{i=1,\ldots,m}$?

3. That is if $X_i \perp X_j \; \forall i=1,\ldots,n$ and $j=n+1,\ldots,m$ then $(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \perp (X_{n+1},\ldots,X_m)$.

I think that the answer is no also for this one but any clarification and references for further study would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_i, X_j) = \mathbb{P}(X_i) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_j)$  when $i \not= j$ is "pairwise independence" but not "mutual independence"

Comment: @Henry thank you for your reply! Can you give me some insights about the third question?